# How to non-specifically filter columns for NULL values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

Quick question, probably has a binary answer.

Given the below:

```
columnA  columnB  columnC column..? columnZ
1        2        NULL    2         2
2        2        NULL    NULL      2     
3        NULL     NULL    2         NULL
```

Is there a way I can write a query that will display only the columns that do not have a total combined NULL result? something like:

select (IS NOT NULL) from x.table where columnZ = 2;

returns:

```
columnA  columnB  column..? columnZ
1        2        2         2
2        2        NULL      2
```

eliminating the useless columnC which has no useable data, without *specifically* referencing it, as before I run the query I don't know which columns will contain useful data?

Cheers!

Comment: There is no easy way.  You can only do this using dynamic SQL, because a SQL query has a fixed set of named columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Cheers, I will take a look into that. At this point though it's starting to get overkill. I just don't want to scroll right heaps.

Comment: **Why** do you need to do this? Whatever problem you are trying to solve, do you think this is the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well what you can Do is run a select statement where category IS NOT NULL. Which will return the columns which have non null values for that particular category. Or you run a select statement where the category IS NULL, and depending on the conditions remove that column. Because there are multiple categories you would need to check for each.